# CMake: Linking to locally built static libraries outside of project directory

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I'm in the process of converting several projects to use CMake as the build system. These projects have some shared libraries between them that I would like to maintain separately from the projects, with the projects statically building the application and libraries together.

The desired directory structure would look something like this;

```
repos/
   common/
      LibA/
         CMakeLists.txt
       src/
          CMakeLists.txt
          <Lib sources>
       build/
          LibA.lib
     <other libs>
   AppA/
      CMakeLists.txt
      src/
          CMakeLists.txt
          <App sources>
      build/
         AppA.exe
   <other apps>
```

The CMake files I've made thus far are;

**LibA/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("LibA")

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("src")
```

**LibA/src/CmakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_library(
    LibA STATIC
    "Animal.cpp" 
    "Animal.h" 
    "Dog.h" 
    "Dog.cpp"
)

set_property(TARGET LibA PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

**AppA/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("AppA")

# Include sub-projects.

add_subdirectory("../common/LibA" "build")

add_subdirectory ("src")
```

**AppA/src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_executable( AppA
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(AppA LibA)

set_property(TARGET AppA PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

With this setup, running cmake on AppA is successful, however, main.cpp cannot find Animal.h.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Animal.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    Animal* ann = new Animal();
    ann->speak((char*)"Rawr");

    return 0;
}
```

I assume I'm not linking to LibA properly in AppA's CMake files. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any good examples of how to link outside of a project's subdirectories statically.

Comment: `ann->speak((char*)"Rawr");` I'm sure this (effectivly an) `const_cast` can be avoided by simply declaring the parameter as `char const*`. `const_cast`s are always suspicious and even more so, if a C style cast is used which almost always reads to me as "I don't care what you do here, compiler, just leave me alone with those casting problems". As for your cmake problem: Add `target_include_directories(LibA PUBLIC .)` to make the necessary include dir available to linking targets. Note: better move public headers to their own dir.

Comment: Btw: Imho in this setup find scripts for the subprojects could be beneficial: Simply have a `repo/cmake` directory, add it to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, preferably in the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` via `list(APPEND)` and use e.g. `find_package(LibA REQUIRED)`. In `repo/cmake/FindLibA.cmake` you can then check for the existance of target `LibA` and if it doesn't exist, use `add_subdirectory` to add it allowing you to add the logic to include arbitrary subprojects in arbitrary other parts of the project without worrying about multiple includes. Also this allows you to easily use prebuilt binaries.

Comment: The Animal class and main.cpp were just quick and dirty prototypes I made to work out the CMake functionality. The actual project(s) are much more complex.  However, adding `target_include_directories(LibA PUBLIC .)` to **LibA/src/CMakeLists.txt** worked perfectly!